# Auto clicking a button on a page using tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I know nothing on how to code so i need help making this one. I'm trying to auto click a button on a page as soon as it come up. I'm using the Chrome extension called tampermonkey to do this.

The HTML button i'm trying to click is this:

```
<div class="content preAppear fadeIn" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; top: 277px; left: 730px;">
    <div class="header cf">
        <a class="btn_close"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="innerContent" style="display: block;"><p>Are you sure you want to leave this conversation?</p><p><a data-conversationid="12874874" class="btn_blue btn_confirm">Leave</a><a class="btn_blue btn_cancel">Cancel</a></p></div>
</div>
```

I have no idea what i'm doing so please be patient and ask me anything. I've look at other people similar problems and I can't figure out how to use it for mine. I need specific help on this.

Comment: it depends on the behavior when you click the button. If it does not execute any JavaScript you can just do something like `.content.preAppear {display:none !important;}`

Comment: Also duplicated by several other questions.  Easily found by search.

Comment: It's not the same. I've looked on other posts and they haven't worked for me. Im sure someone who codes a lot would know how to modify someone's else's solution to fit their own but i have no idea how.